# yii2 multiple dynamic form wbraganca (what are the class that are needed to be differentiated)

Tags: php, yii2, dynamic-forms

I am having problem with multiple dynamic forms in a single form.

When I press add on the second dynamic form it adds the 1st dynamic form.

What are the changes I need to make in the form?

Comment: [May be this will help](http://wbraganca.com/yii2extensions/dynamicform-demo3/source-code)

Comment: Mind adding what you have tried ?

Comment: Insane Skull it is an example for nested form, I am having problem with multiple. That particular example didnt helped me.

Comment: wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget; is the widget I have been using.

Answer (score 0):

Only now I'm using this class.

If you have 2 form you have to change few items in second DynamicFormWidget.

**First form:**

```
DynamicFormWidget::begin([
    'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
    'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
    'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
    'limit' => 5, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
    'min' => 0, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
    'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class
    'deleteButton' => '.remove-item', // css class
    'model' => $user[0],
    'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
    'formFields' => [
        'name',
        'email',
    ],
]);
```

and

```
<div class="pull-right">
<button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
</div>
```

**Second form:**

```
DynamicFormWidget::begin([
    'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper',
    'widgetBody' => '.container-items',
    'widgetItem' => '.item2', // CHANGED
    'limit' => 5, 
    'min' => 0,
    'insertButton' => '.add-item2', // CHANGED
    'deleteButton' => '.remove-item2', // CHANGED
    'model' => $car[0], // CHANGED
    'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
    'formFields' => [
        'color', // CHANGED
        'type', // CHANGED
    ],
]);
```

and

```
<div class="pull-right">
<button type="button" class="add-item2 btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
<button type="button" class="remove-item2 btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
</div>
```